# Monitoring and tracking workflowapplication instances

Tags: entity-framework, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

We created our custom workflow host that use workflowapplication instances.
Now we are working in monitoring and tracking, and as far as I know the solution for both is using a TrackingParticipant. I know that there are a lot of support for WF services for monitoring using AppFabric, but not for workflowapplication.

So, we decided to create a TrackingParticipant that fires different events depend on the type of the trackingrecord and then we have 2 services that are subscribed to some of the events. These 2 services write in different databases using entity framework: MonitoringService(custom tables in the InstanceStore) and TrackingService (Framework tables?).

The performance is really important for us because we could have a lot of workflow instances running at the same time (+10000).

So, my questions are:
- Are there tools(event collection, ETW,..) that offers the framework that we are not using and can improve the performance?
- Is it wrong to use EF in wf tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an EtwTrackingParticipant you can use to write tracking into the the windows event log that will work just fine with a WorkflowApplication.

Other than that using EF to save the tracking information to the database is no problem. Keep in mind that this will generate extra overhead so it is best to have the TrackingParticipant put messages in a queue and do the actual database inserts on a background thread if you expect any serious load.